# Remove duplicates based on multiple columns and datetime

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I want to remove duplicated rows that has same visitor_id based on the earlier datetime. For example, for visitor_id 2643331144, I want to pick row 1 as it has the earlier visit date time, and also keep channel and visit_page for the same row. And for visitor_id 1092581226, I want to keep row 3.

| rowno | visitor_id | datetime | channel | visit_page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2643331144 | 10/3/2021 4:05:29 PM | email | landing page |
| 2 | 2643331144 | 10/3/2021 4:05:39 PM | organic search | landing page |
| 3 | 1092581226 | 10/7/2021 1:08:12 PM | email | price reduced |
| 4 | 1092581226 | 10/7/2021 1:08:44 PM | organic search | landing page |
| 5 | 1092581226 | 10/7/2021 1:09:04 PM | paid search | unknow |
| 6 | 1092581226 | 10/7/2021 1:09:05 PM | email | price reduced |

And I want a result look like below:

| rowno | visitor_id | datetime | channel | visit_page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2643331144 | 10/3/2021 4:05:29 PM | email | landing page |
| 2 | 1092581226 | 10/7/2021 1:08:12 PM | email | price reduced |

I used below query but the total visitor number is over-deduped. But without using partition, total number will be double counted as same visitor has multiple channels and pages during same session.

```
with T as
(select *, row_number() over (partition by visitor_id order by datetime asc) as rank
from table A)

select distinct visitor_id, channel, visit_page
from T
where rank=1
```

Comment: @Lion why do you have `count(distinct visitor_id)` in your result if you don't want count?

Comment: @Lion and can you please explain what is now working with your query?

Comment: @GuruStron The total count(distinct visitor_id) from my current query is much lower than count(distinct visitor_id) from table A so I think my current query is over-deduped. I think two numbers should be same or at least close.

Comment: @Lion sounds very strange, TBH. Though the provided data does not reproduce the issue. You can try something like [this](https://pastebin.com/81rhq01f). But it should give the same result.

Comment: @GuruStron Thank you! However, I'm using Athena sql and it doesn't support `min_by` function. Do you know what is the replacement?

Comment: @Lion I just run this query on Athena and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only problem is rownum in final output you can "recount" it with `row_number() over (order by datetime asc) as rownum` in final select:

```sql
with cte (
   visitor_id 
  ,datetime   
  ,channel    
  ,visit_page 
) as (
    values 
     (2643331144,'10/3/2021 4:05:29 PM','email','landing page'),
 (2643331144,'10/3/2021 4:05:39 PM','organic search','landing page'),
 (1092581226,'10/7/2021 1:08:12 PM','email','price reduced'),
 (1092581226,'10/7/2021 1:08:44 PM','organic search','landing page'),
 (1092581226,'10/7/2021 1:09:04 PM','paid search','unknow'),
 (1092581226,'10/7/2021 1:09:05 PM','email','price reduced')
)

select row_number() over (order by datetime asc) as rownum,
    visitor_id,
    datetime,
    channel,
    visit_page
from (
        -- inlined your WITH clause into subquery
        select *,
            row_number() over (
                partition by visitor_id
                order by datetime asc
            ) as rank
        from cte
    )
where rank = 1
```

Output:

| rownum | visitor_id | datetime | channel | visit_page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2643331144 | 10/3/2021 4:05:29 PM | email | landing page |
| 2 | 1092581226 | 10/7/2021 1:08:12 PM | email | price reduced |